# Ruby On Rails signup process in detail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, registration

This is Sucindran from coimbatore. I am fresher for ROR can any one refer me the coding how simply create registration and login process.

Answer (score 1):

Install gem 'nifty-generators'.

Read tutorial.

There are a lot of another gems for it, but this gem is simplest.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Sucindran, here's a great resource for learning how to create a signup/login process with Rails. [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#top)

Answer (score 1):

There are also railscasts about it:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/21-super-simple-authentication

http://railscasts.com/episodes/67-restful-authentication

http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic